# BigQuery , Union issue / Error: Syntax error: Expected keyword ALL or keyword DISTINCT but got keyword SELECT at [16:3]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, union

Currently, I'm trying to connect 4 tables together and display only 5 columns and union them all to one table.

This is the query:

```
SELECT
  id,
  platform,
  url,
  profileImageUrl,
  name
FROM (
  SELECT
    f.id AS id,
    f.platform AS platform,
    f.url AS url,
    f.profileImageUrl AS profileImageUrl,
    f.name AS name
  FROM
    `l.p.link_f_main` AS f UNION
  SELECT
    i.id AS id,
    i.platform AS platform,
    i.url AS url,
    i.profilePicture AS profileImageUrl,
    i.fullName AS name
  FROM
    `l.p.link_i_main` AS i UNION
  SELECT
    t.id AS id,
    t.platform AS platform,
    t.url AS url,
    t.profileImageUrl AS profileImageUrl,
    t.name AS name
  FROM
    `l.p.link_t_main` AS t UNION
  SELECT
    y.id AS id,
    y.platform AS platform,
    y.url AS url,
    y.profileImageUrl AS profileImageUrl,
    y.name AS name
  FROM
    `l.p.link_y_main` AS y ) as main
```

This is the error:

```
Error: Syntax error: Expected keyword ALL or keyword DISTINCT but got keyword SELECT at [16:3]
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax): `UNION { ALL | DISTINCT }`. So you have to use either `UNION ALL` or `UNION DISTINCT` (which is exactly what the error message says).

Comment: @HoneyBadger - Error: Column 1 in UNION ALL has incompatible types: INT64, INT64, INT64, STRING at [16:3]

Comment: Then fix your datatypes so they are compatible.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Have missed so silly thing )))) Thank you

Comment: @HoneyBadger can you some up your comments into the answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer:

1) For Big Query have to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

2) Datatypes for all union columns should be the same.
    -

1. I had an issue that one on the columns was `STRING` - `INT64, INT64,
   INT64, STRING`
2. So I change the rest columns to `STRING` as well, to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation: `UNION { ALL | DISTINCT }`. So you have to use either `UNION ALL` or `UNION DISTINCT` (which is exactly what the error message says). As per HoneyBadger user mentioned this is the correct explanation.

Comment: The reason as i mentioned the comment as aswer was to make sure it shows up as answer. The answer which was voted up is not correct.